# Show Alert if Any Bad/Filtered Word is present in form input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get rid of the SPAM contact mails I am receiving through my website.

I have a list of banned words, one per line format. Now I want to implement something that can show an alert if any of the banned words is present in the form inputs and prevents the form submit. How can I do that?

Here is the code I tried, but that failed. I don't know how to match that one per line words or phrases with the input data.

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="/sendmessage.php">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
<input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" />
<input type="textarea" id="message" name="message" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message" />
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#submit").on("click",function() {
        var name = $("input:text[name='name']").val();
        var email = $("input:text[name='email']").val();
        var subject = $("input:text[name='subject']").val();
        var message = $("input#message").val();
            var badwords = (abc // first bad word, followed by a carriage return
                            bcd // second bad word, followed by a carriage return
                            cdf // third bad word, followed by a carriage return
                            ...
                            the bad phrase // bad phrase, followed by a carriage return
                            another bad phrase // another bad phrase, followed by a carriage return
                            ...
                            xyz
                            );

        /* I am not sure what to do from now on */ 

                if (name || email || subject || message ) {
                    alert("Your Message Contains Bad Words, Please Remove Them Before Proceeding");
                    return false;
                }
        /* I am not sure what to do */ 
    });
});
</script>
```

Please Help

Comment: Are you sure spammers are not sending spam to your email address directly? That, or turning off javascript, will make the restrictions meaningless to them.

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure SPAMs are coming from the contact us page of my website.

Comment: JavaScript won't help. Spammers POST their crap directly to your form's `action`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hers is the solution:

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="/sendmessage.php">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
<input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" />
<input type="textarea" id="message" name="message" />
<input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
$("#submit").on("click",function() {
    var name = $("input:text[name='name']").val();
    var email = $("input:text[name='email']").val();
    var subject = $("input:text[name='subject']").val();
    var message = $("input#message").val();
        var badwords = ["abc", "bca", "hai hello"];

    /* do this */ 

        if($.inArray(name, badwords) !==-1 || $.inArray(email, badwords) !==-1 || $.inArray(subject, badwords) !==-1 || $.inArray(message, badwords) !==-1)
            {
                alert("Your Message Contains Bad Words, Please Remove Them Before Proceeding");
                return false;
            }

});
});
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bittu4u4ever/8gF8k/

To automatically convert those words with line break into an array:

```
var words = "abc\nbca\nhai hello";
var badwordsarray = words.split("\n")
```

Comment: Great!! But is there any way to automatically convert those words with line break into an array?

Comment: ya you can do that. i have updated the code for that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if($.inArray(name, badwords) !==-1 || $.inArray(email, badwords) !==-1 || $.inArray(subject, badwords) !==-1 || $.inArray(message, badwords) !==-1) {
        alert("Your inputs contain Bad Words, Please Remove Them Before Proceeding");
                    return false;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a version that checks if the bad word even exsists in the entire string? 
example: 
var badwords = "\nkill"; 
input usage: killer finding the first three characters and yet banning the usage?

Would seriously help me out if you have an example of such
Kind regards,